# Is is possible to call a function inside a .inc file of a module via drush eval?

Tags: 7, drush

I have a module with additional (.inc) files containing functions I need to run via Drush. I know it is possible to run `drush eval`, but when I try to do it for those functions I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function my_module_my_function() in /usr/share/php/drush/commands/core/core.drush.inc(1037) : eval()'d code on line 1

This command works (the function is in the .module file).

```
drush eval 'my_module_cron();'
```

This command does not work (the function is in the .inc file).

```
drush eval 'my_module_my_function();'
```

Is there any workaround, besides moving the function in the module?

Comment: Is your inc file included/required on the module file? or in your .info file? This should work as long as drupal knows about the inc file from a .info file or it's included/required in your .module file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could add [module_load_include()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) to your eval code like you would anywhere else.

Like this:

```
drush eval "module_load_include('inc', 'my_module', 'INCLUDE_FILE_NAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION'); my_module_my_function();"
```

Comment: Also works for `.install` files, for example: `drush eval "module_load_include('install', 'my_module', 'my_module); my_module_install();"`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get `Division by zero core.drush.inc(1168) : eval()'d code:1` when I call `module_load_include`.

Comment: @mbomb007: what version of drush are you using and what is the command you are running?

Comment: Never mind. I was using the same type of quotes both inside and out. `drush eval 'module_load_include('...`

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 8 you can use the following method.

```
drush php-eval "module_load_include('install', 'my_module', 'my_module'); my_module_update_8020();"
```

I used it for running updates that were already run.