# Alternate ways to call a function inside a .module file of a module

Tags: drush

I have installed [quickdraw](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/britell/2150221) module and it needs some additional functions to be executed using drush commands. For that, I used the following drush commands:

```
drush php-eval "quickdraw_xx_xx_additionalfunction();"
```

But it returns an error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function quickdraw_facet_navmenu_materialize() in /usr/local/Cellar/drush/6.3.0/libexec/commands/core/core.drush.inc(1100) : eval()'d code on line 1
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                [error]
Error: Call to undefined function quickdraw_facet_navmenu_materialize() in
/usr/local/Cellar/drush/6.3.0/libexec/commands/core/core.drush.inc(1100) : eval()'d code, line 1
```

As discussed in this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144710/is-is-possible-to-call-a-function-inside-a-inc-file-of-a-module-via-drush-eval). I have tried [module_load_include()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7), which returns the same `Fatal error`.

Also tried `drush eval 'quickdraw_xx_xx_cron();'` - Didn't work!!!

Is there any alternate ways to execute the function or how can I resolve the issue. Any ideas??

**NOTE:** The additional function is defined in `quickdraw_xx_xx.module` file, I assume it is not being recognized.

Comment: It might be a good idea to post the command you tried with  module_load_include(). I think that should work and maybe there's an easy fix that can be applied to it.

Comment: @Thomas4019, do you have any idea about that easy fix

Comment: not really. I would look where the function quickdraw_facet_navmenu_materialize() is being defined and try including that file as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a drush command. It's not very hard:

```
function quickdraw_xx_xx_drush_command() {
  $items = array();
  // Name of the drush command.
  $items['quickdraw_xx_xx_additionalfunction'] = array(
    'description' => 'A quickdraw additional function.',
    'callback' => 'quickdraw_xx_xx_additionalfunction',
  );
  return $items;
}
```

This way, Drupal will bootstrap and everything you need will be there, including dependencies to other files.

Comment: index for the items must be like quickdraw/xx/xx/additionalfunction right?? And what is the drush_command() here and do I need to call it after updating the .module file??

Comment: index must be the name of the drush command. Later you will be calling 'drush quickdraw_xx_xx_additionalfunction' instead of 'drush eval ...'. Don't use any slashes in there!

Comment: I've executed the command, it says: The drush command quickdraw_xx_xx_additionalfunction could not be found.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/drupal-create-drush-command/ and http://knackforge.com/blog/narendran/creating-custom-drush-command

Comment: Have you cleared drush cache? 'drush cc drush'

Comment: yes, I have cleared the drush cache

Comment: Did you put the it in your .module file?