# How to change Drupal module load sorting(weight) order

Tags: 7

I need to understand how can we change module weight.

- Do we really change that value for custom module.
- What are the default values?
- If we change weight value what will be effect on Drupal bootstrap process?

Comment: WHy you want to change the module load order? May be you want to change hook implementation module call order?

Comment: I have written one custom module, which implements hook for workflow module and commerce module. and I am getting error like `Fatal error: Call to undefined function workflowfield_property_info_callback() in sites/all/modules/entity/modules/field.info.inc on line 30`. May be I think I have change order for my custom module

Comment: AFAIK Drupal loads all enabled modules (well, only the .module of every enabled module) and the starts to use them. May be your workflowfield_property_info_callback() function is in another file that's not the .module?

Comment: No this function is already define in `workflow_field/workflowfield.field.inc`

Comment: You have to include that file, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144710/is-is-possible-to-call-a-function-inside-a-inc-file-of-a-module-via-drush-eval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using [Modules Weight](https://www.drupal.org/project/modules_weight) module.

> This module provide admin interface for users/people has the access to
>   modules page to reorder the module weights as they want.